# Android : Can't change the playback speed. MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I want to change the playback speed.
But it doesn't work properly on Android 7.0 (Xperia XZ).
When the playback speed is 1.0f, it will be played.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val file: File = File("/storage/emulated/0/sound_file_1.mp3")
        val fis: FileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
        val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            setDataSource(fis.getFD())
            prepare()
            start()
        }
        mediaPlayer?.setPlaybackParams(mediaPlayer?.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(1.5f))
    }
}
```